# Dell XPS 9510: Drivers for sound / Nvidia / Ethernet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, drivers, dell-xps

I just bought a new Dell XPS 9510 to be my (first) daily use Ubuntu Laptop (I use Ubuntu at work, and had a 9 year old mac at home - context shifting was annoying).

I love the hardware, but its taken quite a bit of work to get up and running with Ubuntu, initially had no wifi driver, and had to install that via tether, run updates, then Nvidia driver, a couple of other drivers and just played sound from the speakers and the sound is terrible. I am dual booting with Windows, and sound is ok on Windows.

Looking at Dells website there is no list of drivers for Ubuntu, so i am apt getting what i think is correct, but from a novice perspective, how do i know if the drivers i am installing are correct? How do i keep them up to date? How do i know what i am missing?

Thank you for your time.